# ng-file-upload not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I want to input an image and upload it to a folder on my local machine.

HTML :

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
   <h4>Image</h4>
   <input type="file" ng-model="post.primaryImage" />

</md-input-container>
```

CONTROLLER :

```
  var url = '/Users/my.name/Desktop/images'   


  $scope.OnSubmit = function() {
    //ResourceService.addMachine.save($scope.post);
    console.log( $scope.post );
    $scope.upload(file);
  }


  $scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'url',
        data: {file: file}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.data);
    });


    }
```

Infact the image is not getting input .
When i print scope.post a blank object is printed on the console.
I have read several answers on the topic , but there isn't any answered question on how to upload the image on the local system's folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ngf-select` like this :

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <input type="file" ngf-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = ['$scope', 'Upload', function($scope, Upload) {
    $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
       for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
          var $file = $files[i];
             Upload.upload({
             url: 'my/upload/url',
             file: $file,
          })
       }
     }
  }];
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxo3sk41/886/)

Hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks a lot . The image is getting input now. The only problem is it doesn't upload on "/Users/my.name/Desktop/images". localhost:8888/Users/my.name/Desktop/images 404 (Not Found) . I want the image on my system.What url should i mention.